# Using ant to edit/append data to a text file

Tags: java, ant, build

I am trying to add a property to a .jad file in my ant build process.

Is there a task in ant to do this? All I need to do is add a line of text to the end of a text file but I cannot find a task to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this will work. Testing it now.

```
<concat append="true" destfile="app.jad">foo: bar</concat>
```

Comment: <concat append="true" destfile="app.jad">foo: bar</concat> Needed to add the append="true" or else it wipes the file and leaves only the added line.

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative, using the ant echo task

```
<echo file="app.jad" append="true">hello world
</echo>
```