# Ant delete all lines from text file after a certain keyword

Tags: ant

Is there a possibility to delete all text lines using Ant in a text file that are after a specific keyword? - after the first occurrence of the keyword.
Example

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
.....
Line1000
```

I want to delete everything that is in that file that is after "Line3" keyword excluding that line.

Comment: Perhaps [Replace Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) can modify the files; by the way, the file is on a remote server or local?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754438/using-ant-to-edit-append-data-to-a-text-file)

Comment: its a local text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant's `replaceregexp` task can handle this pretty easily:

```
<replaceregexp
    file="input.txt" 
    match="(.*Line3).*"
    replace="\1"
    flags="s"
/>
```

Brief explanation: The regex pattern captures everything up to and including "Line3" in a group, then continues to match the rest of the input. The replacement consists of only the captured group, effectively deleting the part you don't want. The `s` flag is switched on so that newlines are matched with the `.` wildcard.

Comment: It works, but it is very slow. Isn't there any other solution?